# Align something in the center of a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

say i have a list of footie scores and each one is a div

```
<div> Arsenal 2 0 Southampton </div>
<div> Tottenham 3 2 Burnley </div>
<div> Manchester City 0 5 Spurs </div>
```

I know how to align them if I want say all the first letters to sit underneath each other but how would i do it so that all the scores would sit underneath each other? thus meaning that the other text was not aligned

exactly how it is done here:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/scores-fixtures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is helpful. Please check the updated code

```css
div {
text-align:center;
display:flex;
}

div span {
  width: 40%;
}

div span.score {
  width:20%;
}
div span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}

div span:last-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div> <span>Arsenal</span> <span class="score">2 0</span> <span>Southampton</span> </div>
<div> <span>Tottenham</span> <span class="score">3 2</span> <span>Burnley</span> </div>
<div> <span>Manchester City</span> <span class="score">0 5</span> <span>Spurs</span> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center the text, all you need to do is wrap the divs in another div with a class. Then use the CSS styling `text-align: center` to center the text.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o4gLnhLd/

If you're wanting the scores to all align in the middle. You're probably better off using a table than divs.

Either way will require you to split the data into 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<table>` and use `float` to align them as you want, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xM49X/).

Though you still have to make the border transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```css
.score-card {
  margin:5px;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee; 
}

.left {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 5px;
}

.right {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.team {
  margin: 5px;
}

.score {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ffd536;
}
```

```html
<div class="score-card">

  <span class="left">
    <span class="team"> Arsenal </span>
    <span class="score"> 2 </span>
  </span>

  <span class="right">  
    <span class="score"> 0 </span>
    <span class="team"> Southampton </span>
  </span>

</div>

<div class="score-card">

  <span class="left">
    <span class="team"> Arsenal </span>
    <span class="score"> 2 </span>
  </span>

  <span class="right">  
    <span class="score"> 0 </span>
    <span class="team"> Southampton </span>
  </span>

</div>

<div class="score-card">

  <span class="left">
    <span class="team"> Arsenal </span>
    <span class="score"> 2 </span>
  </span>

  <span class="right">  
    <span class="score"> 0 </span>
    <span class="team"> Southampton </span>
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: add another field in your answer there is a mis alignment. Please update with same css you will get the result.

Comment: there are more football clubs, add manchester united instead of arsenal in one field, or many other clubs are there.

Comment: Bro you didn't understood let me give you a fiddle link of your answer with different names

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/kms9kdzx/1/ I hope you have your answer now

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect, but this should give you a good starting point:

```css
.left{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  text-align:right;
}

.right{
  display:inline-block;
  width:45%;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Arsenal 2</div> <div class="right">0 Southampton</div>
<div class="left">Tottenham 3</div> <div class="right">2 Burnley</div>
<div class="left">Manchester City 0</div> <div class="right">5 Spurs</div>
```